# Homework involving unitary diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I was given as an assignment to diagonalize the following matrix:

> $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
> \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
> \sin\theta & \cos\theta
> \end{array}\right)$

I started by finding the eigenvectors and got:

> $v_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
> 1\\
> -i
> \end{array}\right)$,  $v_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
> 1\\
> i
> \end{array}\right)$

then I normalized the vectors and composed a unitary matrix:

> $U=(v_1|v_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 1\\
> -i & i
> \end{array}\right)$

The problem is in the final step:

> $U^{*}AU=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & i\\
> 1 & -i
> \end{array}\right)\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
> \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
> \sin\theta & \cos\theta
> \end{array}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 1\\
> -i & i
> \end{array}\right)\right)$

This doesn't produce a diagonal matrix.

Is there any mistake in these stages?

Many thanks.

Comment: just a quick question, what did you get for your eigenvalues?

Comment: @imranfat $\lambda_{1}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta,\ \lambda_{2}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$

Comment: yep, that's what I got, so far so good

Comment: What do you get for $U^*AU$?

Comment: The matrix must be a real symmetric one to apply the above result(spectral theorem)

Comment: So isn't this way to diagonalize: A = SDS^-1 with matrix S being a 2 by 2 matrix with the eigenvectors as columns, D is a 2 by 2 matrix that has corresponding eigenvalues on its diagonal, zeros elsewhere, and S^-1 is the inverse of S? That' s what I have from my notes :)

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu this doesn't work with any normal matrix?

Comment: For any matrix i guess its not true. In those cases this $U* $ must be replaced by $U^{-1}$. But in this case it wont matter as $U^{-1}=U^*$. I cant really point out the problem right now. I am thinking over it and will let you know as soon as I solve the problem.

Comment: @martini $U^*AU=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2\cos\theta & -2i\sin\theta\\
-2i\sin\theta & 2\cos\theta
\end{array}\right)$

Comment: I think you must review your computation. As far as i have checked it produces a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu you're referring to this:
$U^{*}AU=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & i\\
1 & -i
\end{array}\right)\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{array}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
-i & i
\end{array}\right)\right)$?

Comment: Yes i am referring to $U^*AU $ which is diagonal.

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu You're right.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a matter of computational mistake:

$$P=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}\;1&1\\\!\!-i&i\end{pmatrix}\implies P^{-1}=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}1&\;i\\1&\!\!-i\end{pmatrix}$$

And now check that you indeed get

$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\theta}&0\\0&e^{-i\theta}\end{pmatrix}$$

as expected.

Comment: that is indeed what I wrote:
$U^{*}AU=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & i\\
1 & -i
\end{array}\right)\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{array}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
-i & i
\end{array}\right)\right)$

Comment: Indeed. It was just a matter of computation.